# Student Information System Class assignment Vector search

Tags: c++, system

lets say that i have a text document containing this data

```
First Name    Last Name      ID         Tuition   GPA
Alex           Robinson       02341     1400.50   3.45
John           Brown          043261    1200.00   3.21
Rachel         VanGorp        77239     600.00    4.00
James          Smith          89167     1150.55   1.45
Juan           Garcia         23165     1200.00   3.33
Lindsey        McDonald       32501     1340.50   2.25
Tom            Barry          78442     500.00    3.85
Gwen           Poss           30029     1150.50   3.85
Janice         Jones          44560     2200.50   2.45
Jack           Price          99314     1850.55   3.12
```

and I import this list of items into a vector, here is my student class and my classOfStudents class.  assistance with this info would be great.  i'm lost and don't know where to go.  just references and a point in the right direction would be great!

```
     class student
      {
    public:
        student()
        {
            firstName = "";
            lastName = "";
            ID = "";
            tuitionBalance = 0.0;
    GPA = 0.0;
}
student(string first, string last, string id, double tuition, double gpa)
{
    first = firstName;
    last = lastName;
    id = ID;
    tuition = tuitionBalance;
    gpa = GPA;
}

void openIF()
{
    inFile.open("students.txt");
}
void setFirstName()
{
    inFile >> temp;
    firstName = temp;
}
void setLastName()
{
    inFile >> temp;
    lastName = temp;
}
void setID()
{
    inFile >> temp;
    ID = temp;
}
void setBalance()
{
    inFile >> tuitionBalance;
}
void setGPA()
{
    inFile >> GPA;
}
void closeIF()
{
    inFile.close();
}

string firstName, lastName, ID;
double tuitionBalance, GPA;
    private:

ifstream inFile;
char temp[128];
    }

class classOfStudents
{
public:
    vector<student> students;

    classOfStudents()
    {
        student Students = student(firstName, lastName, ID, tuitionBalance, GPA);
        students.push_back(Students);
    }

    void findStudent()
    {
        int searchID;
        cout << "Enter ID of student" << endl;
        cin >> searchID;
        find(students.begin(), students.end(), searchID);
    }

private:
    string firstName, lastName, ID;
    double tuitionBalance, GPA;
}
```

How would I pull the rest of the information with just the `ID` of the student?

Comment: You could make a `map` with the `ID` as the key and `student` as the value.

Comment: The most basic solution is just iterate the vector until you find a `student` with the right ID; Cyber approach serves to begin playing with data structures (a little bit) more complex.

Comment: @Cyber when i tried to map it Visual Studio told me i was putting to many arguments on the map

Comment: @user3658110, in order to do it the way Cyber suggests, you you need to have an std::map<int, student>, where the first "int" is the Student ID. Then you will look up the map with the student's ID.

Comment: @SJuan76 would you be able to guide me in the right direction for that? just some references to read.  I am a beginner when it comes to vectors and really any kind of collection

Answer (score 0):

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class student
{
public:
string firstName, lastName;
int ID;
double tuitionBalance, GPA;

student(){}

student(string fName, string lName, int id, double tBalance, double gpa)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    ID = id;
    tuitionBalance = tBalance;
    GPA = gpa;
}
};

class classOfStudents
{
public:

std::map <int, student> StudentMap;

classOfStudents()
{
    student Students = student("Firstname", "Lastname", 123, 0.00, 4.00);
    StudentMap.insert(std::pair<int, student>(123, Students));
}

void findStudent()
{
    int searchID;
    cout << "Enter ID of student" << endl;
    cin >> searchID;

    if (StudentMap.find(searchID) == StudentMap.end())
    {
        printf("Student not found");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Name: %s %s ", StudentMap[searchID].firstName, StudentMap[searchID].lastName);
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Check the updated code. You can use the insert method to insert a pair and [] operator can be used for finding the value for a given key.